# Turn off keyboard navigation on jQuery prettyphoto

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

We are using prettyPhoto:

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/
For our portfolio. This allows us to show a video, image or SWF. 
When we display a SWF game that uses the arrow keys, it conflicts with prettyPhoto navigation.
See this example of a game we have added:

http://www.letsdesign.co.uk/#!prettyPhoto/0/
This messes up worse in IE on PC. 
however the game is playable on Firefox for Mac, this is the state we would like for all browsers.

We would like to find a way to turn off the navigation of PrettyPhoto (by using arrow keys), so it doesn't conflict with any in-game controls. We have other games to add, but we can't add them until this is fixed. Does anyone have a solution to this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

After trying to disable keyboard shortcuts including (left and right) by setting the "keyboard_shortcuts" param to false I resorted to overriding the changePage method and called the method from the changepicturecallback method.  I find this makes it easy to choose different experiences of prettyPhoto without having to edit core files (which I would never recommend).

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
  changepicturecallback: function(){
    $.prettyPhoto.changePage = function(){};
  },
});
```

Take a look at the prettyPhoto params they are very powerful when combined properly.

Answer (score 1):

In the JavaScript file of Prettyphoto set the **keyboard_shortcuts** to *false*

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I'm using the follwing code:

`<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){

                $("a.buy-this[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                    keyboard_shortcuts: false,
                    custom_markup: '<div id="" style="width:650px; height:500px"><?php echo $form; ?></div>',
                    theme: 'light_rounded',
                    social_tools: '',
                    changepicturecallback: function(){ initialize(); }
                });

            });
        </script>`

Answer (score 1):

I found a really hacky way to disable the arrow key functionality. In my jquery.prettyPhoto.js file I just commented out `$.prettyPhoto.changePage('previous');` and `$.prettyPhoto.changePage('next');`.

It will mean that arrow navigation doesn't work at all, but I don't need it for my project anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug, unfortunately. I have modified the code and now it works great.

Here's the bug. There is a piece of code like this:

```
switch(t.keyCode){case 37:e.prettyPhoto.changePage("previous");t.preventDefault();break;case 39:e.prettyPhoto.changePage("next");t.preventDefault();break;case 27:if(!settings.modal)e.prettyPhoto.close();t.preventDefault();break
```

change this by the following one

```
if (settings.keyboard_shortcuts) { switch(t.keyCode){case 37:e.prettyPhoto.changePage("previous");t.preventDefault();break;case 39:e.prettyPhoto.changePage("next");t.preventDefault();break;case 27:if(!settings.modal)e.prettyPhoto.close();t.preventDefault();break}
```

Now the author's setting, called keyboard_shortcuts will work great if you set it to false.

This is valid for the minified code, I haven't check if the bug exists in the non-minified code (if available).

Good luck!

George