# Disabling Arrow Keys in Prettyphoto

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts, prettyphoto

I am trying to disable arrow keys in PrettyPhoto, but even when I include keyboard_shortcuts:false, if someone hits right or left it reloads the frame, resetting the form inside it. I can't completely strip out the keyboard functionality out of the JS because I need it for a picture gallery that is also on the site.

I make this call to prettyPhoto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                    deeplinking: true,
                    keyboard_shortcuts: false,
                    });
                });
```

Does anyone know of a way to disable the arrow keys for one instance of Prettyphoto

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this similar post which potentially can help you disable everything.  You can then add whatever functionality you want.

- [Turn off keyboard navigation on jQuery prettyphoto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620663/turn-off-keyboard-navigation-on-jquery-prettyphoto)